# React create an thumbnail for each object dynamically

Tags: arrays, reactjs, foreach, ecmascript-6, thumbnails

Hello guys im trying to create an div for each thumbnail in my `personas ={[]}` it should use this.props.personas.map something like this

```
{this.props.personas.map(thumbnail => {
      return <div><img src={this.props.thumbnail /}></div>
  })}
```

i already tried this but failed here is my bin. [Bin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kn3dhgYPlWSCsRRrUfA)

any suggestions?  what im doing wrong

Comment: Check your console. Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: Key should be unique, i have added the index as key in your bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the src for the images is in the personas array (i know you call it thumbnail, but for consistency sake let's use persona instead)? If so, you should use persona instead of this.props.thumbnail

```
{
  this.props.personas.map((persona, i) => {
    return <div key={i}><img src={persona.thumbnail} /></div>
  })
}
```

The answer aside, it is good practice to use `key` prop on dynamically generated components.  Read about keys here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: It should be `persona.thumbnail`, `persona` is an object.

Comment: @SaugatAcharya Nice catch. Edited my answer.